# PHP - Checkbox values is displayed in the textbox in edit form

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have made an edit form on a bunch of checkboxes and a textbox.
Here is my code

```
<?php
require("config.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM contracts WHERE id= '$id'";
$result = $con->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{   
$subunit = explode(',',$row['subunit']);
?>

<form action="" method="GET">
ID: <?php echo $id; ?><br>
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
Sub-Category Unit:
<input type="checkbox" name="subunit[]" value="OFL" <?php in_array('OFL', $subunit) ? print "checked" : ""; ?>>OFL
<input type="checkbox" name="subunit[]" value="HVTL" <?php in_array('HVTL', $subunit) ? print "checked" : ""; ?>>HVTL
<input type="checkbox" name="subunit[]" value="PINS" <?php in_array('PINS', $subunit) ? print "checked" : ""; ?>>PINS
<input type="checkbox" name="subunit[]" value="FEG" <?php in_array('FEG', $subunit) ? print "checked" : ""; ?>>FEG
<input type="checkbox" name="subunit[]" value="PC" <?php in_array('PC', $subunit) ? print "checked" : ""; ?>>PC
<input type="checkbox" name="subunit[]" value="PI" <?php in_array('PI', $subunit) ? print "checked" : ""; ?>>PI<br> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp 

Others:
<input type="text" name="subunit[]" value="<?php echo $row['subunit']; ?>"/>
<br><br>

<input type="submit" name="edit" value="Update" />
</form>

<?php
}
if(isset($_GET['edit']) ){
$subunit = isset($_GET ['subunit']) ? implode(",", $_GET['subunit']) :null;

 $upd= "UPDATE `contracts` SET `subunit` = '$subunit' WHERE `id` = '$id'";

  if($do_upd = $con->query($upd)) {
    echo "Update Success<br>";
    echo "$upd <br>";
    echo "$do_upd <br>";
    echo "<a href='viewcheck.php?id=$id'>View</a>";
} else {
    echo "Update Fail<br>";
    echo "$upd <br>";
    echo "$do_upd <br>";
    echo "<a href='viewcheck.php?id=$id'>View</a>";
}
}
?>
```

The code is working fine. When I went back to the edit form again after I have updated the data, it looks something like this.

[image: capture1]

I don't want all the checkbox values to be displayed in the textbox. Yet I want to use the same attribute for both checkbox and textbox. How do I do this?

[image: capture2]

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

**NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the while loop below the line `$subunit = explode(',',$row['subunit']);` need to place this code:

```
$array_all=array('OFL','HVTL','PINS','FEG','PC','PI');
$a=array_values(array_diff($subunit,$array_all));
```

$a will give you the values for `Others` text field. You need to replace the value of Others as:

```
<input type="text" name="subunit[]" value="<?php echo $a[0]; ?>"/>
```